# Disable error logging in firebase 3

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

how do I disable firebase error message loggin in console
even though I am handling error firebase logs its own error message.
look at the attached image
[image]

Comment: please use text in this case, not images.

Comment: The Firebase auth backend apis return 400 on errors. For example the verifyPassword api will 400 if the password supplied is incorrect. Depending on the browser you are using and the level of logging, these errors will be logged.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @bojeil! :-)

Comment: Was wondering this too. This seems really bad? Our api keys are getting printed to the console by default without any way to stop it?

Comment: I'm catching the error as shown in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password, but the error is still being logged to the browser console, how can one prevent this?